# How to do inheritance between models and ActiveRecord::Base?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a project Ruby on Rails and two models using inheritance:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name
   validates :name, :presence => true
end

class B < A
   attr_accessible :age
   validates :age, :presence => true
end
```

In my a_spec.rb I can check this:

```
it 'should be invalid' do
  @a.should_not be_valid
end
```

But in my b_spec.rb I can't check this:

```
it 'should be invalid' do
   @b.should_not be_valid
end
```

And I receive the bellow error:

> 1) B should be valid
>        Failure/Error: @b.should_not be_valid
>        NoMethodError:
>          undefined method `age' for #<B id: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>        # ./spec/models/b_spec.rb:6:in`block (2 levels) in '

Anyone could help me to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you post the entire error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails does not normally do relationships that way.

Unless you have a really good reason, all your models should inherit from ActiveRecord::Base

You can use single table inheritance (STI) to model inheritance by adding a _type field to the model in question.

More on Active Record at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html